# oracle trigger on delete

Tags: oracle, triggers, cascading-deletes

Okay so I have been stuck on this for about 2 hours now and I still couldn't find a solution.

I have 2 database instances.

Site 1 has lets say,
Table A 
id
attrib1
foreignKey - (primary key of table B)

Site 2 has,
Table B
id
attrib1

I want to create a trigger on delete of a record of Table A. Which basically checks if Site 2 Table B has a reference to that particular record. If it does have that record, I want to prevent the deletion from happening. So far I have come up with this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_DEALERSHIP_USAGE
BEFORE DELETE on TBL_CARDEALERSHIP
FOR each ROW
 declare
  rowcnt number;
  begin
  SELECT COUNT(DEALERSHIP_ID) INTO rowcnt 
  from TBL_SALESPEOPLE@SITE1
  where DEALERSHIP_ID = :NEW.DEALERSHIP_ID;
  if (rowcnt>0) THEN
     Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'This dealership is used in the sales people table.');
  end if;
end;
```

Then I do this,

```
delete from TBL_CARDEALERSHIP
where DEALERSHIP_ID='83';
```

But it still deletes it, even thought I have a record in the database

Comment: In a delete trigger you need to reference the **old** record e.g. `where DEALERSHIP_ID = :OLD.DEALERSHIP_ID;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DrabJay put it in the comments, the NEW record in a delete trigger is NULL, since it's after the deletion.

But, frankly, you're going at this wrong. This sort of thing should be done with foreign keys, not in a trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CARDEALERSHIP (
    ... columns ...
    CONSTRAINT fk_salesppl FOREIGN KEY (dealership_id)
        REFERENCES tbl_salespeople (dealership_id)
);
```

Comment: A constraint over a database link?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that. You're right, that wouldn't work across a link.